# How to type check each element of 1 dimensional ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a situation:

a numpy ndarray say:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.asarray([1,2,3,4])
#How can I check if all element in this 1 dimensional ndarray is type int
#so can I use something like
check=np.apply_along_axis(type,0,a) #this doesn't work
result=check.all()
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy arrays have a single NumPy [dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) that applies to all members of the array. You can check whether that dtype is an integer dtype:

```
>>> numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4]).dtype
dtype('int32')
>>> numpy.array([1, 2, 3.0, 4]).dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> numpy.issubdtype(numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4]).dtype, numpy.integer)
True
>>> numpy.issubdtype(numpy.array([1, 2, 3.0, 4]).dtype, numpy.integer)
False
```

Incidentally, if you want to be able to mix floats and ints in a NumPy array, you probably shouldn't be using NumPy at all:

```
>>> numpy.array([1, 2.0])
array([ 1.,  2.])
```

The only NumPy dtype that allows mixed types for its elements is the `object` dtype, and it doesn't support a lot of the things that make NumPy useful.